# Как создать бота (ИИ) в Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет! Недавно начал учиться создавать игры и решил создать один зомби шутер. Все сделал, но не могу найти ассет, который имеет при себе 3д модель зомби и встроенный ИИ. Может подскажите как решить проблему?

Comment: начните с тупого ии, а-ля если игрок в зон видимости идти на него, если нет - стоять чесать любое место по желанию, или ходить туда - сюда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Моделей можно не только создавать но и найти в Assets Store. Про ИИ не нужно мучатся: Unity уже имеет встроенный ИИ - NavMeshAgent называется. Читайте [эту](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/Navigation.html) статью в документации и сами всё поймёте.

Answer (score 1):

Модели персонажей и анимацию можно найти и приобрести в Unity Asset Store. Там же есть и наборы со скриптами. Есть и бесплатные, но читайте условие лицензии если вы собираетесь создавать коммерческий продукт.